# How HF wire antennas on older aircraft are protected from lightning and static discharge?

Tags: radio-communications, lightning, static-electricity

For HF antennas installed on some older aircraft with wires running from points on the fuselage to the tail, what precautions are used to prevent lighting strikes or P-static accumulation from damaging the HF antennas or interfering with the communications? Are the wires shielded and would that be enough to prevent damage if lighting strikes?

Comment: This might also be a question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, since it's about electromagnetic protection of electronics.